# Не работает TOAD for Oracle

Tags: oracle, windows-7

Программа TOAD for Oracle периодически перестает работать и выключается. Если его попробовать снова запустить, то он не будет соединяться с базой. Только после того как компьютер будет полностью выключен и снова включен коннект к базе проходит. Антивирус проблем не выявил. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А в менеджере задач он после падения виден?

Comment: Простите, неправильно выразилась. Toad теряет связь с базой, находящейся на другом компьютере в локальной сети. Причем рядом в той же сети стоит другой компьютер, точно также соединенный с базой и у него таких проблем с Toad не возникает.

Comment: Попробуйте  - `tnsping db` -  если и он не соединяется, отключите огненую стенку.

Comment: а может на это повлиять то, что брандмауэр неправильно работает? т.е. в ответ на команду tnsping выходит ошибка, что пути не найдены. Огненная стенка же  в это время не отвечает и выводит ошибку при попытки войти в ее настройки.

Comment: Не задумываться,  отключите. Он нужен как калоши в солнечную погоду.

Comment: Премного благодарна за помощь!) Выяснилось, что помимо всего прочего, в реестре на этом компьютере отсутствовал раздел Oracle. Стоило его туда импортировать с другого такого же компьютера, как все заработало. Осталось понять, почему он удалился...

Comment: Не стоит благодарности. Рад, что удалось устранить ошиибку.